# Magento Fatal error: Class ‘Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Form_Renderer_Config_DateFieldsOrder’

Tags: magento

I get this error message
“
Fatal error: Class ‘Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Form_Renderer_Config_DateFieldsOrder’ not found in \app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php on line 564

when I click on system -> configuration-> catalog. The version of my Shop is Magento 1.6.2 and the Extension is 0.9.18-Unirgy_Giftcert.

I am grateful for any help
Thanks in advance
Amro

Hallo,

Ich bekomme diese Fehlermeldung, wenn ich auf System ->Konfiguration-> Katalog klicke. Die Magento-Version ist Magento 1.6.2 und die Erweiterung ist Unirgy_Giftcert-0.9.18.

Ich bin dankbar für jede Hilfe wink
Vielen Dank im Voraus
Amro

Answer (score 1):

Does your system have a file at

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Form/Renderer/Config/DateFieldsOrder.php ?
```

If so is this file readable by PHP?  Does it contain the same class definition as a stock installation of your system?  Has your Varien_Autoload class been modified?

Magento's trying to instantiate a  `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Form_Renderer_Config_DateFieldsOrder` object but can't find the class.

Comment: +1 for Alan answer. In my CE 1.6.2.0 I have this file in place.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! the file was not there.

I created this file. Now the problem is fixed. But I have now a new error. I think this is related to the expansion Unirgy_Giftcert-0.9.18. In view of the product are cross-sell, upsell, and footer does not appear. The same problem also appears in the cart.

Comment: Could be anything Amro, especially on a system with missing files.   I'd concentrate on learning how Magento works so you can debug these issues yourself